# Fill DB field with two datas (foreign keys)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I got one table (name) where I save names and a table (anrede) for the salutation.
Now, if people set a new contactname, the can set for example: John (as prename), Doe (as surname) and Mr. (as salutation) so I got the data "Mr. John Doe".
[image: names table]
[image: salutation table]

Now I got the problem with multiple academical grades.
In german for example he can be "Dr. John Doe" (if hes a doctor) or "Prof. Dr. John Doe" (if he got a doctor and a professor grade).

I saved all salutaions in the "anrede" table, but I DONT want to save "Dr., Prof. and Prof. Dr." but only Dr. and Prof.

The salutation is saved as foreign key (anrede_id) in the "name" table.

So is there any possibility to save multiple data sets in there?

Comment: It sounds like you have a M:N (Many-to-many) relation between name and anrede.  You will need to create another table that correlates those two fields.  (Were you thinking of trying to save a list of anrede ID's in the name table?  If so, I would not recommend that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a third table like AgRizzo recommended.  It could look something like:

**Link_name_anrede**
name_id
anrede_id

For every new salutation a person has you would add a record to the **Link_name_anrede** table.

Then to get a list of the salutations a person has use the following query

```
SELECT salutation 
FROM anrede 
    INNER JOIN Link_name_anrede ON anrede.ID = Link_name_anrede.anrede_id
WHERE name_id = 3
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, sorry for my late response. Just to resume: so if "john doe" has 2 salutations (like in example Dr. Prof.) I have to create 2 records in Link_name_anrede, so there would be something like name_id 3 | anrede_id 1 and name_id 3 | anrede_id2 ?

Sorry I never worked with m:n relations

Comment: Do i have to define the foreign for the lookup table or the other? Like:  
`ALTER TABLE Link_name_anrede
ADD FOREIGN KEY (name_id)
REFERENCES Name(Id)`  

or  

`ALTER TABLE name
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Link_name_anrede_id)
REFERENCES Link_name_anrede(id)`

Comment: Yes, I would definitely define `name_id` and `anrede_id` as foreign keys

Comment: For each salutation you have tied to a person you would have a separate record in the `Link_name_anrede` table.  For instance if the `ID` for the user John Doe is 3.  The following records could be in the `Link_name_anrede` table: `3 | 4` and `3 | 5`.  Which would mean he is both a Dr. and Prof.